# Is there a correct way to handle Inlines in DataGridTemplateColumn TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm using a TextBlockFormatter to highlight specific parts of text in a DataGridTemplateColumn -> TextBlock

DataGridTemplateColumn

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="2.5*" Header="{DynamicResource TEXT}" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock base:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText="{Binding prettyText}"                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

TextBlockFormatter:

```cs
public class TextBlockFormatter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FormattedText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(RequestTextBlockFormatter),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnFormattedTextChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnFormattedTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textblock = (TextBlock)d;
        //textblock.Inlines.Clear();
        List<SplitText> splitTexts = TranslationActions.getSplitetTextFromString(e.NewValue.ToString());

        Color textColor = SomeColor;

        foreach (SplitText splitText in splitTexts)
        {
            FontWeight fontWeight = Convert.ToBoolean(splitText.isBold) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
            FontStyle fontStyle = splitText.isItalic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;
                
            if(splitText.isColor) 
            {
                textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(splitText.text){Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(textColor), FontWeight = fontWeight,FontStyle = fontStyle });
            }
            else
            {
                textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(splitText.text){FontWeight = fontWeight,FontStyle = fontStyle });
            }
       }
    }
}
```

After about 12 Rows in the DataGrid the TextBlock alread has Inlines and starts repeating data.
Is there a way to prevent this without clearing the Inlines every time?

Comment: Which properties are set by the `DataGrid`?

Comment: <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="Name" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeaderWidth="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

Comment: Tried to set `EnableRowVirtualization=false`?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to build the new `Run`s from scratch each time (by clearing `textblock.Inlines`), or you will have to compare the new formatted text to the old one and only change what needs to be changed - which is a much more complicated task.